# Calculating the Dimension of a Subspace of $C\in Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C\in \text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$. Then which of the alternatives are correct:

1. $\operatorname{dim}\langle I,C,C^2,\dots,C^{2n}\rangle$ is at most $2n$
2. $\operatorname{dim} \langle I,C,C^2,\dots,C^{2n}\rangle$ is at most $n$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem Also, you only have $n+1$ elements in your first list!

Comment: Apologies. Corrected my question.

Comment: @wj32: didn't get it. Please elaborate.

Comment: Cayley Hamilton shows that every matrix satisfies its own characteristic polynomial, in particular, $p(C) =0$ for some polynomial $p$ of degree $n$. Hence $C^n$ can be written as a linear combination of $I,C,...,C^{n-1}$.

Comment: Both statements are correct, but the second is strictly stronger than the first.

Comment: @copper.hat: Here the subspace is generated by {$I,C,...,C^{2n}$} not by {$I,C,...,C^{n}$}.

Comment: I understand. It follows that any higher power of $C$ can be written in terms of $I,C...,C^n$.

Comment: @copper.hat Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2):

Following Julian's suggestion:

Cayley Hamilton shows that every matrix satisfies its own characteristic polynomial, in particular, $p(C)=0$ for some polynomial $p$ of degree $n$. Hence $C^n$ can be written as a linear combination of $I,C,...,C^{n−1}$.

It follows by induction that any higher power of $C$ can be written in terms of $I,C,...,C^{n−1}$.

Hence both statements are correct, as Marc pointed out, but the second is stronger.